# Flutter macOS app: Some of the items in macOS application menu are not getting translated

Tags: flutter

I am working on flutter macOS application and trying to translate the options in the application menu. I have added the properties in the Info.plist file, for the supported languages. The problem is that some of the items remain untranslated. Is there a way to fix that without building custom menu using PlatformMenuBar class?

[image]